# Formula counting based on two conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I am struggling with a formula in Google Spreadsheet.

Here is what I want to achieve:
If a column in a book is not null and if another column in another book is having a specific value, then counting 1. Then summing up all rows.

Example case: Defect tracking.
If the test cases column 'defectID' has a value and that in another book, this defect does not have the status "Closed" (a specific column), then count it as 1.

Here is the formula I have but it's failing:

```
=COUNTIFS(ISEMPTY('Test Cases'!N3:N), FALSE, Defects!I3:I,"<>Closed")
```

Would you know how I can combine functions to have this?

Answer (score 2):

The arguments of `COUNTIFS` must alternate between ranges and conditions applied to those ranges. The condition "not blank" is expressed as "<>". (And "is blank" would be "=". In the context of this command, the lack of a thing to compare to is understood as comparing to empty string.)

```
=COUNTIFS('Test Cases'!N3:N, "<>", Defects!I3:I,"<>Closed")
```

## Remarks

`ISEMPTY()` is not a supported function in Google Sheets. By the other hand, similar functions like `ISBLANK()` require a value, not a range/array as an argument.

## References

- [Google spreadsheets function list - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks Norman, this seems to work, however I have an error message because my ranges are not same length so I need to rework the case.

Comment: Yes, they certainly need to be of the same size for the logic to work. Providing an explicit number of the bottom row is one way; there are others.